# Xcode free provisioning: The 'Apple Push Notification' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications, sideloading

I am trying to use xcode free provisioning but I am getting the following problem

[image]

I have  disabled Remote Notification after getting this problem but it still does not go away.

[image]

How to fix this problem

xcode version 7.2
ios version 9+

*Note:*

xcode has created a certificate for me .I could see this in keychain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the certificate from the keychain.
Remove your account from the xcode->preference->Accounts. Add your account again.
The issue will be resolved.
The remote notification feature is not available for free apple developer account.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a shortcut for those who tried the delete certificate way but still not working:

Find your project's projectName.xcodeproj,click "open content",edit "project.pbxproj" with a txt editor :

change:

```
com.apple.Push = { 
enabled = 1; 
};
```

into:

```
com.apple.Push = { 
enabled = 0; 
};
```

Redo the build and this time no error on push : )

Answer (score 3):

To right click on the projectName.xcodeproj -> Show Package Contents -> open the project.pbxproj -> search the "com.apple.Push" -> set enabled = 0